# Change default Windows Explorer file browser size and position

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Many programs use the Windows Explorer file browser when opening/saving/etc a file as shown below. Is there any way to change the default size and position of the file browser's window whenever a program open it?

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: only with 3rd party tools and product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK thanks but my question is on-topic: if you don't want to name the tools just post your comment as an answer.

Comment: try this tool: http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

Answer (score 4):

The size and position of the window depends completely on the program;  some programs change the position, some can't even resize, and some pick up your OS default.  To save a larger Explorer window size/position, open Windows Explorer, adjust as you want it, then hold down Ctrl-Shift while you click the red X (top right) to close it. This will remember the size/position for the next time you open Explorer.

Programs such as Word and Wordperfect will remember the last position and size you chose for the browse window, for that program only.

And some programs require that you actually open a file after you resize/reposition the window, in order to remember the changes you made.

Comment: So if there is a 'OS default', how do we change this?

Comment: Change the OS default using Windows Explorer & the method described: open it, adjust as you want it, then hold down Ctrl-Shift when click the X at the top right.

Comment: I think the question is about the 'Save as' etc. dialogs, not normal explorer windows.

Comment: Holding CTRL+SHIFT then clicking X doesn't work if you use a utility like Sizer to size/position the window. After using a utility like this you need to start dragging a resize, even if you just let go a second later without any movement.

Answer (score 1):

Extensive search in [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/windows-10-file-explorer/71ce8b7c-cb6e-4f2c-b0da-79f05840dc9d) support [forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop-insiderplat_pc/setting-window-size-and-position/8359bc93-ba41-42c4-b291-db806ef5eb25) and elsewhere reveal no solution within Windows itself. [CmdNow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/#synopsis) is an open source solution freely available, and [ShellFolderFix](https://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html) is available freeware also intended to solve this, until Microsoft provides a solution.